# setting $REPLY to function arg not working

Tags: bash

I've decided to create fn for a validation while loop that I'll be reusing throughout my code:

```
loopFN() {
   while true; do
      if [ "$1" == "null" ] || ([ "$2" == "phone number" ] && ! [[ "$1" =~ $phone_regex ]]); then
         printf 'enter a valid %s\n' "$2"
         read
         $1=$REPLY
      else
         break
      fi  
   done
}
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
   local number="null"
   loopFN "$number" "phone number"
```

and my regex expression for the phone number is:

```
phone_regex="^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

the error im getting is:

```
./newmenu.sh: line 27: null=dasd: command not found
```

where "dasd" is my input when prompted

is it bad practice to reuse a while loop? should I just rewrite it however many times? or is my syntax wrong somewhere?

the problem is around here i guess (the line 27 that the error is referencing):

```
     $1=$REPLY
```

where I'm trying to set the variable that was passed in to the fn, which in this case would be $number, my initial thought was that it wasnt working because the var was local, but I removed the local keyword and the error persists

EDIT:

I've added some changes as per advisement:

```
loopFN() {
   while true; do
      if [[ $1 = null ]]; then
         printf>&2 'enter a valid %s\n' "$2"
         IFS= read -r "$1"
      elif [[ $1 = null || ( $2 = 'phone number' && ! $1 =~ $phone_regex ) ]]; then
         printf>&2 "enter a valid phone number\n"
         IFS= read -r "$1"
      else
         break
      fi  
   done
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1=$REPLY` is not understood as a variable assignment because what's left of the `=` (`$1`) is not a valid variable name, so it's just treated as a command argument or list of command arguments (as `$1` and `$REPLY` being unquoted, are  subject to split+glob) the first of which is treated as the command name.

You'd need:

```
eval "$1=\$REPLY"
```

To ask the shell to evaluate `contents_of_$1=$REPLY` as shell code, and assuming the contents of `$1` is a valid variable name, that would assign the value of `$REPLY` to the corresponding variable (and if `$1` was `reboot;foo`, that would reboot obviously).

Here you could also do:

```
IFS= read -r "$1"
```

Which would call `read` with the contents of `$1` as argument, and `read` doesn't care and would have no way to  know anyway whether that variable name was passed literally or the result of an expansion.

That's still a command injection vulnerability (like when `$1` is `` foo[`reboot`] ``).

In any case, the syntax to read a line is `IFS= read -r line`, not <strike>`read line`</strike>.

Also note that `(...)`, outside of the Korn-style `[[...]]` construct is to start a subshell, your

> ```
> if [ "$1" == "null" ] || ([ "$2" == "phone number" ] && ! [[ "$1" =~ $phone_regex ]])
> ```

Should rather be:

```
if [[ $1 = null || ( $2 = 'phone number' && ! $1 =~ $phone_regex ) ]]
```

If `$1` is meant to be a variable name though, that `$1 =~ $phone_regex` makes little sense. Phone numbers are rarely valid variable names.

If you meant to check the contents of the variable whose name is in `$1`, then you'd use `${!1}` which is the bash syntax to dereference a variable or use ksh93-style name references with newer versions of bash as suggested to you by ChatGPT.

Note that in any case, it's the variable name (`number`) not value (`$number`) that you need to pass to your function.

User prompts and interactions usually go to stderr, stdout being reserved for the actual output your command produces that something else might want to reuse/post-process.

```
printf>&2 'enter a valid %s\n' "$2"
```

With the `bash` shell specifically, you can use the `-p` option of its `read` builtin to issue the `p`rompt (which it will send to stderr as well):

```
IFS= read -rp "Enter a valid $2: " "$1"
```

While in most other Korn-like shells the syntax is:

```
IFS= read -r "$1?Enter a valid $2: "
```

If the function is meant to input a phone number, asking repeatedly until the user enters a valid one,  and return it in the variable whose name is supplied in the first argument then with bash-specific syntax, it would look like:

```
input_phone_number() {
  local -n _var_name="$1"
  local _regex='^[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{4,}$'
  until
    IFS= read -rp 'Please enter a valid phone number: ' _var_name ||
      return # return failure upon EOF
    [[ $_var_name =~ $_regex ]]
  do
    echo>&2 'Not a valid phone number, try again.'
  done
}

input_phone_number number || exit
```

(using `[0123456789]` instead of `[0-9]` as `[0-9]` may match anything, and anchoring the regex at the end as well as at beginning).

For a generic `input` function that takes the  type of input and the validating regexp as argument:

```
input() {
  local -n _var_name="$1"
  local _type="$2" _regex="$3"
  until
    IFS= read -rp "Please enter a valid $_type: " _var_name ||
      return # return failure upon EOF
    [[ $_var_name =~ $_regex ]]
  do
    echo>&2 "Not a valid $_type, try again."
  done
}

input number \
      'phone number' \
      '^[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{4,}$' || exit
```

Note the `_` prefix in the local variables, so the user can do `input type type '^(good|bad)$'` for instance, without a `$type` local variable clashing with the user's `$type` variable they want returned.

Comment: I've added the read changes you recommended, it doesnt recognize correct phone regex and keeps prompting me

Comment: @Mathew, see edit. I initially focused on the syntax issues in your question, but looking at it your function and the way you invoke it makes little sense to me. I'd suggest you clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: I think OP wants `set -- "$REPLY" "$2"` to set $1

Comment: amazing answer thank you, I'm curious about you regex, is '^[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{3}-[0123456789]{4,}$' better than '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$' or are they the same?

Comment: @Mathew, on Ubuntu 20.04 and in the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale as an example, `[0-9]` matches on thousand of different characters (including ߈०१२३४५६७८০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮੦੧੨੩੪੫㏱㏲²³¹¼½¾...), not just 0123456789.

Comment: @Mathew, I changed the `{4}` to `{4,}` to allow 4 or more digits as your original regexp didn't have the `$` anchor, so would have matched `123-123-1234413123` as well (and `123-123-1234anythingelse` for that matters).

Comment: ah okay, I had no clue. My mistake, I meant to add the $ anchor. Thanks for the insight on the fact that [0-9] doesnt just mean 0123456789 on some distros and encodings